# Could my family be receiving my messages

Tags: privacy

I noticed every time my messenger sounds my sons notifications sound. Is this normal?

Comment: You're going to need to provide more info. Messenger - are you talking Facebook ? Is your notification on your phone?  Is it literally every time? Is his notification on his phone?  Have you ever signed in on his device? Tried changing your password?

Comment: And yes Facebook messenger....sorry I'm new

Comment: In the security settings you shold find a 'Where I'm logged in" and from here you should be able to end all logged in sessions.  Once you've done that,  change your password.  I'd suggest you also enable 2 factor authentication, then no new devices can login without a 2fa code sent to your phone.

Answer (score 2):

If it is an account based messenger app then it is likely your account was signed into on his phone at some point and not signed out of. "Is it normal?" is relative. If you have never signed into your account on his phone and he has never used your credentials to sign in then no that is not a standard operating model. However, changing your password is always a good idea and if it were me I would just take a look at his phone and make sure you are not signed into it.